# When Attempting to Run PyInstaller, I get the "Fatal error" Message

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, python-3.7

I am trying to turn a python script into an Windows executable, but when attempting the process, I get the following error.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.523]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\admin>cd C:\Users\admin\Documents\Coding

C:\Users\admin\Documents\Coding>pyinstaller testDirInteractivity.py --onefile
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe" testDirInteractivity.py --onefile'

C:\Users\admin\Documents\Coding>
```

I have reinstalled PyInstaller a few times over. I have no idea what could be causing this problem. So far anything I've tried from other answers I've found around the internet haven't worked out for me. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out running the development version fixed this issue, so yay!